# Strange Heap Corruption Issue?

Tags: c++, heap-corruption

For some reason I'm getting a strange heap corruption from the following class definition file, most likely in the "CreateFromNode" function. Can anyone help me with this? I'd really like to deal with this right now since I caught it, and not see it manifest itself later. Also, no outside forces are modifying any members of this class (or it's members).

```
#include "Object.h"

TmxMap::Object::Object():name(), position(), size(), gid(-1), visible(true),
properties(), image(), polygon(NULL), polyline(NULL), ellipse(false){}

TmxMap::Object::Object(rapidxml::xml_node<>* const& object_node):name(),
    position(), size(), gid(-1), visible(true), properties(), image(),
    polygon(NULL), polyline(NULL), ellipse(false){
CreateFromNode(object_node);
}

TmxMap::Object::Object(TmxMap::Object const& from):name(from.name),
    position(from.position), size(from.size), gid(from.gid),
    visible(from.visible), properties(from.properties),
    image(from.image), polygon(from.polygon), polyline(from.polyline),
    ellipse(from.ellipse){}

TmxMap::Object::~Object(){
DeleteObjects();
}

void TmxMap::Object::CreateFromNode(rapidxml::xml_node<>* const& object_node){
DeleteObjects();

rapidxml::xml_node<>* data_node = NULL;
rapidxml::xml_attribute<>* data_attrib = NULL;

if((data_attrib = object_node -> first_attribute("name")))
    name = data_attrib -> value();

if((data_attrib = object_node -> first_attribute("width")))
    size.x = std::strtol(data_attrib -> value(), NULL, 10);
if((data_attrib = object_node -> first_attribute("height")))
    size.y = std::strtol(data_attrib -> value(), NULL, 10);

position.Set(
        std::strtol(object_node -> first_attribute("x") -> value(), NULL, 10),
        std::strtol(object_node -> first_attribute("y") -> value(), NULL, 10)
);

if((data_node = object_node -> first_node("polygon")))
    polygon = new Polygon2D<int>(data_node);

if((data_node = object_node -> first_node("polyline")))
    polyline = new Polyline2D<int>(data_node);

ellipse = (object_node -> first_node("ellipse") != NULL);
}

void TmxMap::Object::DeleteObjects(){
if(polygon){delete polygon; polygon = NULL;}
if(polyline){delete polyline; polyline = NULL;}
}

void TmxMap::Object::Destroy(){
name.clear();
position.Set();
size.Set();
gid = 0;
visible = true;
properties.Destroy();
image.Destroy();
DeleteObjects();
ellipse = false;
   }
```

Comment: Could you explain why you are not able to debug this yourself?

Comment: I tried? Gdb just told me there was a heap corruption in my main source file (where I instantiated this object). Any pointers on that would work too...

Comment: Have you tried `valgrind` yet?

Comment: Sorry, should've noted that I'm using Windows 7 (and eclipse). Any alternatives?

Comment: [Look](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lagdas/archive/2008/06/24/debugging-heap-corruption-with-application-verifier-and-debugdiag.aspx) at windows way of corruption detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy constructor copies the pointers `polygon` and `polyline`.
This will lead to them being deleted multiple times.

You should copy those objects instead of the pointers.

Comment: This was the problem, thank you.